# How to sort SourceCache, bind to BindingList, and handle IChangeSets manually with Winforms?

Tags: winforms, dynamic-data, reactiveui, bindinglist

I'm using ReactiveUI 9.21 and DynamicData 6.13 together with WinForms.

I did read https://dynamic-data.org/tag/dynamicdata/ and some other resources, but am still confused with `IObservableCache`, `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` and others when dealing with changes in DynamicData collections.

If I have a `SourceCache<Result, string> recoResults` in a model class - how can I sort it there, and then:

**Q1: How do I expose `SourceCache` to be bound to a `BindingList<Result>` (in a view model for a view with a DataGridView)?**

**Q2: At the same time, how do I expose `SourceCache` to be able to react to `IChangeSet`s manually (in a view with a non-reactive plot component)?**

**What I have:**

In the moment, I expose the `SourceCache` unsorted as `IObservableCache` in the model and connect to it the views/view models:

```
public IObservableCache<Result, string> RecoResults { get; protected set; } 
private readonly SourceCache<Result, string> recoResults;

public DropModel()
{
    recoResults = new SourceCache<Result, string>(e => e.ID);       
    RecoResults = recoResults.AsObservableCache();      
}
```

Sorting for the DataGridView's BindingList works in the view model:

```
ResultBindingList = new BindingList<RecoResult>();
DropModel.RecoResults.Connect()
    .Sort(recoResultComparer)
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Bind(ResultBindingList)
    .Subscribe();
```

But I don't know how to do the sorting in the view with the non-reactive plot component:

```
// Still unsorted results:
var observableResults = VM.DropModel.RecoResults.Connect();

// Add result:
var d2 = observableResults.WhereReasonsAre(ChangeReason.Add)
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .ForEachChange(x => {
        // Add to plot
    })
    .Subscribe();

// Remove result:
var d3 = observableResults.WhereReasonsAre(ChangeReason.Remove)
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Subscribe(_ => {
        // Remove from plot
    });
```

**What I'd like to have:**

I'd like to do the sorting in a central place, because the user can choose between two ways of sorting and I want to sync it in all views. I'd like to expose the sorted results as a single property and use it for the BindingList as well as for manual change iterations.

In the model, I already tried:

```
public ??? SortedResults { get; protected set; }

recoResults.Connect()
    .Sort(recoResultComparer)
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Bind(SortedResults)
    .Subscribe();
```

**Q3: What return type is the best to use for SortedResults?**

And in general:

**Q4: When do we use `IObservableCache`/`IObservableList`, and when do we use `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`? And when is `IObservable<IChangeSet<T, key>>` used?**

Comment: Winforms is special in terms of it likes to use BindingList for everything.  So where you see ReadOnlyObservableCollection I would exchange it for BindingList. But essentially you would in some circumstances keep SourceList/Cache confined to your view model (and if not needed by other view models private) and BindingList you would expose to your view.

Comment: The sorting and mutating gets exposed in the collection set by your Bind().